# New Vaadin 14 app fails to run, error "Failed to determine 'node' tool." Missing Node.js and npm tools

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I used the [*Get Started*](https://vaadin.com/start/latest) page to create a new Vaadin 14 app, after choosing the *Plain Java Servlet* option.

The web page successfully downloaded a `.zip` file which I unzipped, and opened with IntelliJ Ultimate Edition version 2019.2. I waited a few minutes while Maven did its thing, downloading and reconfiguring the project. Eventually I went to the Maven panel within IntelliJ, and ran the `Lifecycle` items `clean` and `install`.

I received the following error message on the console.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:14.0.0:prepare-frontend (default) on project acme: Execution default of goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:14.0.0:prepare-frontend failed: 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] ======================================================================================================
[ERROR] Failed to determine 'node' tool.
[ERROR] Please install it either:
[ERROR]   - by following the https://nodejs.org/en/download/ guide to install it globally
[ERROR]   - or by running the frontend-maven-plugin goal to install it in this project:
[ERROR]   $ mvn com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.6:install-node-and-npm -DnodeVersion="v10.16.0" 
[ERROR] ======================================================================================================
```

See [discussion on Vaadin Forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17797984/error-failed-to-determine-node-tool-with-new-vaadin-14-0-0-rc9-project).

I filed [Ticket # 6262 *Configure Maven to automatically install Node.js & npm*](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6262), suggesting to the Vaadin team that requiring and omitting Node.js & npm is a problem.

Comment: Requiring node and node dependencies is a sh**. 1: our DEV machines don't have direct access to internet. 2: setting the HTTP_PROXY doesnt work either with npm. 3: we use vaadin just because we need to keep away from node.js sh** but now hell of a mess just to bring up the starter app (LOL). Spent 1.5 days and still not able

Comment: Just to note. In Vaadin 14.2 the maven plugin has been changed to install node automatically in the project if not found in the system.

Comment: @TatuLund So noted in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57502853/642706). Thanks for the info, and all your work on Vaadin.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Update: Non-issue in 14.2

Vaadin 14.2 & 16 have been changed to now include automatically the necessary *npm* tool in a Maven-driven project. No need to manually install *Node.js* & *npm*.

To quote [this blog post](https://vaadin.com/blog/new-component-features-and-development-time-improvements-in-vaadin-14):

> Automatic Node.js install
>
> Starting from versions 14.2 and 16, the Node.js install (which includes npm) happens automatically. It is installed to a `.vaadin` folder inside the home folder, and reused from there for all Vaadin projects. As before, Node is only used to build the frontend side of things; it does not run after you deploy for production!

And further improvement: *pnpm* instead of *npm*.

> Frontend dependency management that just works - pnpm
>   Behind the scenes, npm has been used to manage frontend dependencies since 14.0. Now, we’ve added support for [pnpm](https://pnpm.js.org/), which introduces the following benefits:
>
> 1. Shorter build time, compared to npm on your local machine and CI system, because [pnpm](https://pnpm.js.org/) only downloads packages once and reuses them from a local cache.
> 2. No need to delete package.json, lock file or the node_modules folder when updating the Vaadin version in your project.
>
> In 14.2, npm is still used by default, but we encourage you to test pnpm and give us your feedback. Trying pnpm is easy: there is no migration, just enable it by using a configuration property or Maven plugin configuration. You can learn more about pnpm [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-switch-npm-pnpm.html). Vaadin 16 will use pnpm by default.

I have verified this works well. I have now manually removed the Node.js/npm installation from my Mac.

---

## tl;dr

The [Vaadin 14](https://vaadin.com/releases/vaadin-14) team expects you to have [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/npm_(software)) tools installed on your computer.

As alternative, Vaadin 14 *seems* to be working with Node.js/npm being automatically installed within your project (rather than globally on your computer) by the [`frontend-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) tool you can specify in your [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Object_Model) file. See [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) snippet below for your POM.

If you would prefer to install Mode/npm globally on your computer, be sure to read the [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57627712/642706) by Tom Novosad.

## Details

[image]

[image]

As of Vaadin 14, the [Vaadin team is switching](https://vaadin.com/releases/vaadin-14#npm):

- From [HTML Imports](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/), [Bower](https://bower.io/), and [WebJars](https://www.webjars.org/)
- To [ES6 Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/), [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)), and [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack), with [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)

…as part of their transition from [Polymer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_(library)) 2 to [Polymer 3](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/about_30).

See blog post, [*Bower and npm in Vaadin 14+*](https://vaadin.com/blog/bower-and-npm-in-vaadin-14-).

Hopefully, as Vaadin-on-Java users, we need not care about these underlying technical details… but for one thing: Unfortunately, the **[*npm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) & [*Node.js*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) tools are required but *not* bundled** within your Vaadin project by default.

You have two solutions:

- Install the tools globally.
- Install within your project.

I prefer the latter. And I prefer to have Maven auto-install them within my project, with less housekeeping for me to do manually.

**CAVEAT:** I do not know the limitations or ramifications of my node/npm-per-project solution. I barely have any idea of the purpose or nature of either node/npm, and have no idea how Vaadin makes use of them. So use this solution at your own risk. All I can say is that it seems to be working for me.

## Add `frontend-maven-plugin` to your project

The [`frontend-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) tool can be used by Maven to download and install Node.js with npm within your Vaadin project.

Open the Maven POM file within your Vaadin project.

Add the following block inside the `<build> <defaultGoal>jetty:run</defaultGoal> <plugins>` element of that POM.

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- Use the latest released version:
        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
        <version>1.8.0</version>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <!-- optional: you don't really need execution ids, but it looks nice in your build log. -->
                <id>install node and npm</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <nodeVersion>v10.16.3</nodeVersion>

            <!-- optional: with node version greater than 4.0.0 will use npm provided by node distribution -->
            <!--                    <npmVersion>2.15.9</npmVersion>-->

            <!-- optional: where to download node and npm from. Defaults to https://nodejs.org/dist/ -->
            <!--                    <downloadRoot>http://myproxy.example.org/nodejs/</downloadRoot>-->
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Of course, you can tweak that snippet to use the latest version numbers. Check [the Node.js page](https://nodejs.org/en/) for the latest versions number.

Notice that we commented-out the `npm` item, as that tool is bundled with the latest versions of Node.js.

Remaining steps:

1. In the `Maven` panel within IntelliJ, run the `Lifecycle` items named `clean` and `install`. Wait a moment as some more items are downloaded and configured. (Notice the item "Installing node version v10.16.3" in your console history.)
2. In that same panel, in the section `Plugins` > `jetty`, run the `jetty:run` item. Wait a moment as the Jetty server launches to run your Vaadin app.

On the console you should see something like this (that [mysterious `Quiet Time` warning is perennial](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/15564634/warning-quiet-time-is-too-low-for-non-native-watchservice-sun-nio-fs-pol) with all releases of Vaadin):

```
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
[INFO] Using Non-Native Java sun.nio.fs.PollingWatchService
[WARNING] Quiet Time is too low for non-native WatchService [sun.nio.fs.PollingWatchService]: 1000 < 5000 ms (defaulting to 5000 ms)
```

3. Point your web browser to: `http://localhost:8080/` to see the "Click Me" button appear, as your app successfully runs.

This solution came from the project page for the Maven plugin [`frontend-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin). Note that the example POM fragment there is incorrect, failing to wrap the `<execution>` tag within a plural `<executions>` tag. I filed [ticket # 838](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/838) there.

You may want to follow [this discussion](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17797984/error-failed-to-determine-node-tool-with-new-vaadin-14-0-0-rc9-project) in the Vaadin Forums.

For your reference, here is a complete POM file to compare to yours.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>acme</artifactId>
    <name>acme</name>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <vaadin.version>14.0.5</vaadin.version>

        <drivers.downloader.phase>pre-integration-test</drivers.downloader.phase>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added to provide logging output as Vaadin uses -->
        <!-- the unbound SLF4J no-operation (NOP) logger implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>jetty:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Jetty plugin for easy testing without a server -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.19.v20190610</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- If using IntelliJ IDEA with autocompilation, this
                    might cause lots of unnecessary compilations in the
                    background.-->
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <!-- Use war output directory to get the webpack files -->
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Use the latest released version:
                https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
                <version>1.8.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- optional: you don't really need execution ids, but it looks nice in your build log. -->
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v10.16.3</nodeVersion>

                    <!-- optional: with node version greater than 4.0.0 will use npm provided by node distribution -->
                    <!--                    <npmVersion>2.15.9</npmVersion>-->

                    <!-- optional: where to download node and npm from. Defaults to https://nodejs.org/dist/ -->
                    <!--                    <downloadRoot>http://myproxy.example.org/nodejs/</downloadRoot>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>9.4.19.v20190610</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <stopPort>8081</stopPort>
                            <stopWait>5</stopWait>
                            <stopKey>${project.artifactId}</stopKey>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-jetty</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>deploy-war</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-jetty</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <!-- Pass location of downloaded webdrivers to the tests -->
                                <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.17</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>true
                            </onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>
                            <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver
                            </rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                            <downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver_zips
                            </downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                            <customRepositoryMap>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers.xml
                            </customRepositoryMap>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <!-- use phase "none" to skip download step -->
                                <phase>${drivers.downloader.phase}</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>selenium</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Note that Vaadin is not "switching to use Node.js and npm", it is migrating from polymer2 / bower / webjars to polymer3 / npm.

Comment: @rmuller I don’t see how “switching” is different from “migrating”, but I did add a couple links for Bower and WebJars. Thanks.

Comment: Forget the switching and migrating wording, confusing to introduce another word, my bad. Most important change is polymer2 -> 3.

Comment: @rmuller I further enumerated the library soup, with links for background info. I like how it turned out. Thanks again.

Comment: I used to let vaadin use my globally installed node.js/npm, until it didn't work for my colleague. Now using local node with the `frontend-maven-plugin` with the exact same plugin definition as you wrote here. Working very fine now for both me and colleague. And I don't get the annoying log-message anymore during install `failed to execute path-to-global-npm/npm.cmd -v`. Thanks for the answer Basil.

Comment: And a note about your caveat about node installations in every project: a coworker of mine focusing on frontend tells me this is actually preferred. The node installation itself will not take much space, and you don't need to require other devs to install it themselves. Having used both ways (locally & globally) I will now always choose local installation.

Comment: @KasparScherrer Unfortunately, after continuing Vaadin problems, I eventually surrendered and installed globally on my Mac.

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is in method

`FrontendUtils::getNpmExecutable(String baseDir)`

from flow-server.jar. This method tries to locate

`node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`

in $baseDir (which is project root folder in case of prepare-frontend goal). When that path does not exist, code continues executing "where/which npm.cmd" to get absolute path of 'npm.cmd'. In my case, got NodeJS installed globally, it returns correct path.

Subsequently code continues trying to execute "path-to-npm.cmd\npm.cmd -v", to ensure that npm.cmd exists and is runnable.

And here is the problem in method:

`ProcessBuilder FrontEndUtils::createProcessBuilder(List<String> command)`

In this method under certain circumstances program code sets environment variable 'PATH' to path of npm.cmd (since ProcssBuilder.environment() returns map which does not contain 'PATH' variable).

Next when trying to execute command 'path-to-npm\npm.cmd -v', the exit value of the process is 1, and stderr is non-empty, because 'chcp' command is called before other stuff in 'npm.cmd' (probably SETLOCAL command), but since now 'chcp' is not in PATH.

Following code evaluates these conditions (exit code 1, stderr nonempty) as an error in execution of npm.cmd and

**Failed to determine 'npm.cmd' tool.**

message is printed.

This happens on my Windows 10, Vaadin Flow 14.0.1, NodeJS 10.16.3 installed globally.

Also got the same issues when running tomcat server with an application, since $baseDir variable contains path to tomcat bin directory.

## Workaround

As a workaround it is sufficient to make symbolic link of NodeJS directory into your project root (and if application running on Tomcat, also make link of NodeJS to Tomcat's bin directory).

Comment: This worked for me. I'd rather have one global install of node than one per vaadin project. The command I used, under an Administrator prompt, was "mklink /d node c:\nodejs", adjusting the paths obviously. This was run inside the vaadin project.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appeared when I was testing new Vaadin 14.
I followed instructions, installed node, but I was doing that with previously opened Idea with another project (other to the this). 
The problem went away only when I restarted Idea.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be more exact there is a case when the real error can be found in the logs at plugin run: 
Command '[C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd, -v]' failed with exit code '1'

but if you run the same command from prompt then you see that nothing wrong with the command and exit code.

As somebody mentioned the problem is that Windows tries to run "chcp" but it is not on the PATH (manipulated by the maven plugin). This happened in my case since I modified in the registry to run cmd always with UTF encoding. In Windows this  is implemented by executing "chcp 65001" along with (before) any batch or command files like npm.cmd ...
My simple solution was copy chcp.com from System32 dir to nodejs directory...

Comment: Copying chcp to nodejs did not work for me unfortunately.I had to use the mklink command to create a symbolic link to the nodejs install folder within the Vaadin project, as described in Tom Novosad's answer.

Answer (score 0):

After the installation of node i had the same problem compiling vaadin app.
It was needed to restart the PC to locate node and run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to add

-Dvaadin.project.basedir="/home/me/project/root/directory"

to your JVM startup args.

The answer came from this thread.

https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18491365/vaadin-14-3-1-prepare-frontend-neede-at-every-eclipse-start

Answer (score -3):

Almost same here. 
Win 10, JDK 11.0.2, node 10.16.2 installed globally

*mvn* results in

```
[ERROR] Failed to determine 'npm.cmd' tool. 
[ERROR] Please install it either:
[ERROR] - by following the https://nodejs.org/en/download/ guide to install it globally
[ERROR] - or by running the frontend-maven-plugin goal to install it in this project:
[ERROR] $ mvn com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.6:install-node-and-npm -DnodeVersion="v10.16.0"
```

So... first advice to *install it globally* fails. second one works.