# Vaadin 14.0.5 fails to find 'npm' (Node.js) when running locally in Tomcat rather than Jetty

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, npm, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Update:

The problem occurs only when running in Tomcat from IntelliJ after having doing a Maven `clean` without doing a Maven `install`.

If I do a Maven `Install` before running my external Tomcat *Run/Debug Configuration*, then the web app launches properly.

So the core problem seems to be that the "Build" stage listed on the *Deployment* tab of that *Run/Debug Configuration* is not actually building.

How to get my *Run/Debug Configuration* settings to actually build the project, so I do not have to remember to manually hit the `Maven > Lifecycle > install` item each time?

[image: screenshot of IntelliJ 2019 > Run/Debug Configuration > Deployment tab]

---

As described in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57502853/642706), I added an entry in my Vaadin 14.0.5 web-app’s Maven POM to install the dependency for Node.js 10.6.3 that comes bundled with the *npm* tool needed by Vaadin.

This works when using the Jetty server specified in that same POM file. I see the logs installing Node/npm on first run. I see the logs checking for Node/npm, and finding it already installed, on subsequent runs. My Vaadin web-app runs successfully when executing from the *Maven* panel within IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2.3 via `Plugins` > `jetty` > `jetty:run`.

When I switch to a runtime configuration using Tomcat 9.0.26 locally, I get an error saying Vaadin cannot find the *npm* tool.

Earlier in the console output I see a positive message about connecting to server.

> Connected to server
>
> [2019-09-29 07:27:09,276] Artifact plainandsimple:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...

But later I get this error message:

```
29-Sep-2019 19:27:11.758 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
    javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: 

======================================================================================================
Failed to determine 'npm' tool.
Please install it either:
  - by following the https://nodejs.org/en/download/ guide to install it globally
  - or by running the frontend-maven-plugin goal to install it in this project:
  $ mvn com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.6:install-node-and-npm -DnodeVersion="v10.16.0" 
======================================================================================================
```

That second option (`frontend-maven-plugin`) is exactly what I had set up successfully as described above at the top of this Question.

➥ Why does this work with Jetty but not with Tomcat?

➥ Can I make a bundled Node.js/npm work with Tomcat?

I am trying to avoid installing Node.js globally on my Mac.

If I manually move the WAR file to Tomcat, and launch Tomcat manually, the Vaadin web-app runs successfully.

Comment: I get this too sometimes, with a completely different setup. I use `liberty:run-server` to run locally, and I have npm and node installed globally on my machine. This occurs very inconsistently and when I install and run again, it works again.

Comment: @KasparScherrer I’m not sure, still experimenting, but it seems if I do a Maven `clean` so there is no prebuilt WAR, then running in Tomcat from within IntelliJ results in this “Failed to determine npm” error. If I do a Maven `install` that results in a built WAR, then I do not get that error (I get very different problems) when running in Tomcat from within IntelliJ. I wonder if this might account for your intermittent error.