# webpack gives messages "Watchdog connection closed. Trying to re-run watchdog." in Vaadin 14 app

Tags: webpack, vaadin, watchdog, vaadin-flow

Running a new Vaadin 14.0.8 app in IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.3 EAP pre-release, on Java 13. I created the project using the "Plain Java Servlet" flavor on the [new project page](https://vaadin.com/start/latest). The only change I made to the POM was adding the npm/Node plugin as described in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57502853/642706).

When I run my web-app using the `jetty:run` item in the Maven panel, I get these messages on the console:

```
[webpack] INFO dev-webpack - Watchdog connection closed. Trying to re-run watchdog.
[webpack] INFO dev-webpack - Watchdog connected.
```

These repeat every minute or so, even before connecting with a browser. When I do connect with a browser, I get another four of these repeated.

➥ What do these messages mean? Is there a problem?

➥ Why so many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those messages are something of no concern. We have accidentally set wrong log level on those. I think we will have changed this for next version.

Comment: Is there currently a workaround? Versions 14.0.7, 14.0.8 and 14.0.9 have this bug