# Running `npm install` to resolve and optionally download frontend dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

how to resolve "Running `npm install` to resolve and optionally download frontend dependencies"

i get this error when i try to debug my springboot/vaadin project. i dont know whats missing.

Pleaase help

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read the guide on how to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, make sure to *include the code that produces the error*. It is almost impossible to help you without seeing what you are doing

Comment: Hi petunia. We need a lot more information about your project setup to be able to help you. Which vaadin version are you using? maven or gradle? what does your .pom look like? When does this error occur?

Comment: Isn't this just a note, that something _will_ happen?  So please provide a full stacktrace or error log and add the relevant parts of the project.  Also newer Vaadin version give clear instructions (or at least help) how to fix the problem (install node or use a plugin for your build tool to provide it)

Comment: Perhaps related: [*New Vaadin 14 app fails to run, error “Failed to determine 'node' tool.” Missing Node.js and npm tools*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57502852/642706)